# Django: How to make buttons disappear/disabled after pushed?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a like/dislike button system in Django, but don’t know how to do the final part of it, namely, making the button disappear/change to the compliment of the button that was pushed. 
Basically, I want to have a "like" button on my template and once it is pushed, then I want the like button to disappear/switch to an “unlike” button so that the user can undo their like if they wish, similar to facebook. How can I go about doing this?

Here’s my template code for the button (the hidden part is used to figure out which post the like button belongs to):

```
<form action="#" method="get">
 <input type="hidden" value="{{postset.id}}" name="postset_id" size="1"/>
 <input type="submit" class="btn" value="+1" name="postlikebtn">
 </form>
```

Here’s my simple views.py for this button (I’m using the djangoratings app for managing the votes so that’s what my code is referencing on the last line):

```
if (request.GET.get('postlikebtn')):
        postid = request.POST['postset_id'] #get the ID of the post that was liked
       c = newpost.objects.get(id=postid) #getting the post
       c.rating.add(score=1, user=request.user, ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']) #add a vote
```

So what can I add to basically make the button disappear when pushed? And then ideally replace it with another button, the “unlike” button?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript (and specially library like jquery) will make this thing easier and intuitive. And also I would not use GET for this, I would use POST since you are making changes in database.

If you don't want to use Javascript, in `request.GET.get('postlikebtn')` function, after votes/likes in database, you render the page again.

Here is some sample, before pressing 'like', you could render the page in following way:

```
<ul>
<li name="postset_id" value="{{postset.id}}" class="not-liked"> ... </li>
...
</ul>
```

So, using CSS, you can style it the you want to. Now, once the `like` is pressed, you render the page again, in this case, you replace the class:

```
<ul>
<li name="postset_id" value="{{postset.id}}" class="liked"> ... </li>
...
</ul>
```

Since you have not given more details about template, I had to assume. If you can post it, I can edit my answer accordingly.

I will also add briefly how you would do it using jquery & ajax. Basically, you would perform following steps:

1. You add an event in javascript which performs some action on every 'submit'
2. Once submit button is pressed, in jquery, you change the class to 'liked'
3. You send the action to backend
4. If everything is successful, no action needs to be performed. If it fails, like in case of backend is down, you change the state back to original and it displays 'like'